# Tell Git to use several self-signed certificates as trusted

Tags: git, ssl

I have several git servers under several self-signed certificates.

I need to add all the certificates as trusted.
I know about flag `http.sslCAInfo` - it works only for one certificate.
I know about flag `http.sslCAPath` - but it doesn't work at all.

```
$ cat .gitconfig
...
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://[server_ip_address]/root/FirstOne.git
[http]
    sslCAPath = /Users/username/certs/
...
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git fetch
Couldn't find host [server_ip_address] in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying [server_ip_address]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to [server_ip_address] ([server_ip_address]) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection:     ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
CApath: /Users/username/certs/
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://[server_ip_address]/root/FirstOne.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

As I see CAFile has a default value and as I understand CAFile has a priority under CAPath. I have tried to set variable `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` an empty value but have got

```
error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile:
CApath: /Users/username/certs/
```

How can I solve this problem?
P.S. - please do not suggest me using `http.sslVerify false` :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I had co-workers fighting with libssl self-signed certificates and paths in the past (not using Git at all, just using libssl) and it appears to be hard and messy and version-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git uses curl (libcurl) for making calls over http (s) and has properties `http.sslCAPath` to define a directory with ssl certificates and`http.sslCAInfo` to describe a file with ssl certificate. Properties are mapped to cult's `--capath` and`--cacert` respectively.

Curl's docs says that there may be different behavior on different OSs. Also `--capath` runs `c_rehash` utility on the directory and the utility may be not installed.

As I researched it is more preferable to use `http.sslCAInfo` against`http.sslCAPath`. `http.sslCAInfo` must direct to file in PEM format. If you want to write several ssl certificates then certificates must be stored in one file one after another.